# Xubuntu: Locale settings in /etc/default/locale are overridden by regional format settings

Tags: xubuntu, locale

I am running xubuntu 14.04 and recently changed my **/etc/default/locale** to

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
**LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"**
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
```

Everything seems to work fine **except the time and numeric format, which is still in german**. Checking with **locale -a** yields:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
**LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8**
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the regional format settings in the graphical interface provided by xubuntu (Start>>Settings>>Language support>>Regional format), which are "**german**" for me. This seems to override my locale settings. **Is there any way to keep these regional settings from overriding the settings in my /etc/default/locale?**

And, yes I did a restart after my changes ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually editing `/etc/default/locale` is usually not a good idea on an *ubuntu desktop.

If you want that the changes affect all users on the system, you can create a file in the `/etc/profile.d/` folder, for instance like this:

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/locale-tweak.sh
export LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Otherwise, to affect your own user only, you can put those `export` commands in your `~/.profile` file instead.

Comment: @asdu52: Glad to hear that. Can you please mark the answer as "best", so others more easily see that the problem was solved.

Comment: I'd like to, but it says I need at least 15 reputation in order to do that. :-S   Maybe a mod can mark the answer?

Comment: @asdu52: I'm not sure, but I think it's _upvoting_ you can't do without a reputation, while you can _accept_ an answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: "is usually not a good idea"? Why exactly? These configuration files are meant to be overridden. Can you provide any authoritative sources for the claim?

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Because the GUI uses it, and manual overrides are easily overwritten. The same is true for `~/.pam_environment` (per user settings). Hence it's better to override through e.g. `/etc/profile.d/*sh` and/or `~/.profile`. (I wrote the code which is currently used by Language Selector and friends.)